# How to change hyphenation but not quotation marks in bibliography with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, hyphenation, babel, csquotes

I'm using `biblatex` with `biber` and an `authoryear` style for my bibliography. My main language is french, but I have different languages in my bibliography (so I load `\usepackage[english, french]{babel}`. I would like biblatex to print bibliography items hyphenated according to their hyphenation field (e.g. no space before double punctuation and question marks), but always with french-style quotation marks. 
When I use `\usepackage[babel=hyphen]{biblatex}`, biblatex uses the hyphenation language (e.g.: english) quotation marks, but doesn't seem to use other rules (such as no space before double punctuation and quotation marks). That's exactly the opposite of what I'm looking for.
When I use `\usepackage[babel=other]{biblatex}`, `biblatex` does use the right hyphenation rules, but still uses the foreign language quotation marks, and also uses the foreign language version of some strings (e.g. 'in' or 'cit. on').

I've looked around quite a lot but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Any idea?

EDIT: here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp, bibstyle=authoryear, natbib=true, babel=hyphen]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{agnew_iv._1987,
  author = {Agnew, John},
  title = {{IV.} Place anyone? A comment on the {McAllister} and Johnston papers},
  journal = {Political Geography Quarterly},
  year = {1987},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {39--40},
  number = {1},
  month = jan,
  doi = {10.1016/0260-9827(87)90030-9},
  hyphenation = {english},
  issn = {0260-9827},
  shorttitle = {{IV.} Place anyone?},
  url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0260982787900309},
  urldate = {2012-08-02}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

 Some text.

 Some text, with a citation \citep{agnew_iv._1987}.

 And now a bibliography.

 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output here is: [image: input]

I would like the same but with French "guillemets" (quotation marks).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even though your question is quite clear, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) might help us. (e.g. What options do you load `csquotes` with?) Just to clarify: You do not only want to change the hyphenation, but also some punctuation behaviour, you do not, however, want to change the quotation marks? Is the punctuation behaviour to be changed in `title`/`subtitle` fields or everywhere for that particular entry (that is "in : Journal" vs "in: journal")?

Comment: Indeed, I should have provided a MWE, but I have to admit I was lazy ;-) `csquotes` is loaded with `autostyle=true`. I want to change hyphenation and punctuation behaviour (actually, I think you're right: only in the title, and some other fields like journal name, book title for @inbooks, etc.), but not the quotation marks, nor the localisation of workds like "in" etc. But for that last matter I can use tricks like `\DefineBibliographyStrings`.

Comment: Well, there is still time :-). It would be very helpful, if you could provide a MWE along with the desired output of some example entries, so we can see exactly what you want. (I for one, have still some trouble figuring out what exactly needs to be changed; the only thing `babel=hyphen` messed up in my test was spacing around colons in foreign language entries.)

Comment: @moewe I've added a MWE.

Comment: Fine! That is very weird indeed, I get the output « IV. Place anyone? A comment on the McAllister and Johnston papers ». (with French spacing), which is, I suppose, what you want. What version of `biblatex`/Biber are you using?

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2013, `biblatex` is 2.7a and `biber` is 1.7.

Comment: Mhhh, that is the most recent version. I'm using MiKTeX though, so maybe someone else might be able to reproduce your result.

Comment: OK, I've found the solution. Thank you for forcing me to devise a MWE, it did help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem actually comes from the `autostyle=true` option passed to `csquotes`. If you remove it, it works just as expected.